# Best pythonic way to find the max value in a matrix of objects

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following code:

```
resdata = dict()
rows = result.rows.all()
for key, group in groupby(rows, lambda x: x.space):
    row = list()
    for item in group:
        cell = {
            'time': item.time,
            'value': item.value
        }
        row.append(cell)
    resdata[key] = row
```

a sample resdata would be:

```
    resdata = [
    {
      "skl": "nn_skl:5608", 
      "cols": [
        {
          "value": 115.396956868, 
          "time": "2012-06-02 00:00:00"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 112.501399874, 
          "time": "2012-06-03 00:00:00"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 106.528068506, 
          "time": "2012-06-18 00:00:00"
        }
      ], 
      "len": 226
    }, 
    {
      "skl": "nn_skl:5609", 
      "cols": [
        {
          "value": 114.541167284, 
          "time": "2012-06-02 00:00:00"
        }, 
      ], 
      "len": 226
    }, 
    {
      "skl": "nn_skl:5610", 
      "cols": [
        {
          "value": 105.887267189, 
          "time": "2012-06-18 00:00:00"
        }
      ], 
      "len": 225
    }
]
```

What I want to do is to get the maximum 'value' and the maximum 'time' among all the cells.

Comment: It would be nice if you gave a data structure that we could actually test on.

Comment: @Nasir: Lattyware brings up a good point, which raises another question.  What are you asking?  Are you wondering how to parse, or just an algorithm for finding the maximum?  It would help if you could include a code snippet that takes care of the stuff you know how so others can focus on the part that you need help with.

Comment: Sorry guys. I will in a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've converted into a Python object with `json.loads` or whatnot, then you want something like:

```
max(b["time"] for b in a["cols"] for a in data)
```

Comment: There isn't really a need to construct a list here, if you just leave out the square brackets you will get a generator expression that will function the same but read a little nicer.

Comment: Yes, I need to get out of that habit

Comment: It's not a big deal in this case, as `max()` will have to consume the whole thing anyway, it's just a little nicer to look at. In any case, +1, a good solution.

Comment: I've never seen a generator expression with multiple `for`s before. Is this a 3.0 thing?

Comment: I've always been able to do it (I'm on 2.7 here), as far as I know it's nothing new...

Comment: You're right, I just found it in the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/). I thought it was 3.0 only because I was getting an error, `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` when I ran your code. It works when I flip the order of the two `for`s though.